# Proper CSS required to make text and href alignment perfect

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to CSS. I have copied a CSS from existing code and changed as below:

```css
.feedback_h1 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-width: 400;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div Class="feedback_h1">
  We will use only personal information. Our <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">privacy 
      policy</a> agreed?
</div>
```

Right now I'm getting result as below:

```
  We will use only personal information. Our
  privacy policy
  agreed?
```

However, I'm expecting a result like (in one line) :

```
  We will use only personal information. Our privacy policy agreed?
```

I think, I need a right alignment (as left is aligned properly) OR
Am I missing something in CSS? What additional attribute can I consider in CSS to make this in a single line?

Is VS 2013 provides a designer view to align cshtml page?

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't have the effect you say. You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though your `<a>` anchor element might have a display of block. This will cause the words wrapped between the anchor elements to have a `width` of `100%` by default.

Try putting the following in your css

```
.feedback_h1 a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`<a>` elements are `display: inline` by default, so not sure why it might be like this. But from the code, that seems to be the most obvious reason your code is having this result.

To figure out what's going on, I would suggest using your browser's inspector tools and directly inspecting the element. It usually helps with debugging to look at the CSS styles applied to an element, and test by unchecking them, or changing them, to see the live effect of this on your site.